# LineChart listener is not working or i miss something

Tags: mpandroidchart

my problem is I set Chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener but when I click on value there is no any action.

my code is :

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
                dataSets.get(dataSetIndex).setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                dataSets.get(dataSetIndex).setCircleColorHole(getResources().getColor(R.color.lavender_indigo));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected() {
                dataSets.get(0).setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gorse));
                dataSets.get(0).setCircleColorHole(getResources().getColor(R.color.gorse));
            }
        });
```

I want to my chart like this :
[image]

The image is not from app. Just design part. I want to make it like that.

Comment: I guess you did ensure that correct implementation is follow such as public class CombinedChartActivity extends DemoBase implements OnChartValueSelectedListener chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this) ?  why not pull the two implementation methods out  on separate blocks to see it helps or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the code you provided but I ran into this issue when I called `chart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false)`

From the names "highlight" versus "selected" if wasn't clear at first sight that the `setHighlightPerTapEnabled` method also disables the `OnChartValueSelectedListener`

My solution was to replace the `OnChartValueSelectedListener` with a `OnChartGestureListener`. Here's a snippet of what I implemented:

```
private class BarChartGestureListener implements OnChartGestureListener {
    private int _lastTappedIndex = -1;

    @Override
    public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
        final Entry entry = _barChart.getEntryByTouchPoint(me.getX(), me.getY());
        if (entry != null && _lastTappedIndex != entry.getXIndex()) {
            final Object data = entry.getData();
            if (Summary.class.isInstance(data)) {
                final Calendar calendar = DateUtils.newCalendar(((Summary) data).getDate());

                _spinnerMonth.setSelection(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {

    }
}
```

In the `onChartSingleTapped` you can get the `Entry` that was tapped and programmatically highlight it or whatever else you want.